# Print a line after Thread.new exit in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Basically I would like to know when the thread created by `Thread.new` exit and puts a line after that. How do I do that?

Comment: I don't know how. I am working on a project that spawn a new thread to send an email using pony. But after I added this function, the project starts to draw a lot of CPU resource. So I was wondering if the spawned thread never actually exit. Appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Thread.join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-join) to block until the thread terminates:

```
thread = Thread.new  # Obviously called with necessary arguments
thread.join
puts "Thread has terminated"
```

Comment: Thread.join is blocking the original thread till the spawned thread terminates? What if I want both thread to run concurrently

Comment: If it runs concurrently how do you know when it terminated? You don't. And can't. You could check periodically by calling [`status`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-status) if that's what you want. Also, the `thread.join` can go *anywhere* after the thread begins executing. It doesn't have to be right after.

Comment: Also, you could just do a `puts` at the end of the code `Thread.new` is executing…

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help! Anyway, I found the unusual high CPU usage. It was totally unrelated. Haha